# Tink: What format does tink give your keys in? Pem or der?

Tags: cryptography, public-key, tink

First time user of tink (and overall cryptography noob, but I'm learning)

I'm able to create a private key using

`tinkey create-keyset --key-template [MY TEMPLATE] --out-format json --out foo.json`

then once I have that file I try to create the public keyset via

`tinkey create-public-keyset --in-format=json --in=foo.json`

The output is

```
{"primaryKeyId":3104918340,"key":[{"keyData":{"typeUrl":"type.googleapis.com/google.crypto.tink.HpkePublicKey","value":"EgYIAxACGAIaYQTKiU+xhistDls5CMGMC311ZRfELnUGdfLXBx++SHiMOMOzsaFryaKljLlHHKegOeC6vbG8AXXpoPrvaouxtU5CgHCXGEczYwo9p/PHN4gKnJFfJJWCerzC5lEtV4SJUVo=","keyMaterialType":"ASYMMETRIC_PUBLIC"},"status":"ENABLED","keyId":3104918340,"outputPrefixType":"TINK"}]}
```

So now I need to send pem across the wire to a server, but my server team keeps telling me that I'm giving them an invalid pem document. I was under the understanding that the valud in the json above is pem format. Any tips?

Comment: PEM format is not exactly a real format, it's basically a header line followed by lines of base64-encoded data followed by a footer lines. See [RFC 7568](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7468) for more details and some examples. If you base64-decode the data in the PEM file the result is often DER. For everything talked about in RFC 7468 its DER. But there are PEM-like key formats, for example SSH2 public keys, that don't encoder DER data. Your example is not PEM because it lacks header lines, and the base64-encoded data is also not DER. So the answer is: neither.

Comment: Possibly of interest to you: [Tink Cryptographic Library, Access Control](https://developers.google.com/tink/design/access_control), sec. *Better way to export a public key*.

Answer (score 1):

As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78046365/tink-what-format-does-tink-give-your-keys-in-pem-or-der#comment137611931_78046365) by [President James K. Polk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/238704/president-james-k-polk), you are not dealing with PEM in the first place.

The output you have shown is a JSON representation of a [keyset](https://developers.google.com/tink/design/keysets), which is Tink's own format for storing keys. The value inside the `value` field is base64-encoded binary data, not PEM or DER formatted data.

[Tink key objects](https://developers.google.com/tink/design/key_objects) are structured in a way that encapsulates all necessary information for cryptographic operations, including the key material itself and metadata like the key type, status, and key ID. The [`keyData` field](https://developers.google.com/tink/wire-format) within a Tink key object contains the actual key material, encoded in a type-specific format and usually base64-encoded in JSON outputs.

So you would have to:

- use the `typeUrl` field to understand the cryptographic algorithm and key type (e.g., RSA, ECDSA, AES).
- decode the base64-encoded `value` field from the `keyData` object to get the raw key material.
- use appropriate cryptographic libraries (depending on the key type) to interpret the raw key material and convert it into a standard format. For asymmetric keys like RSA or ECDSA, you would typically convert the key material into a key object and then serialize it to PEM format.

As a generic pseudo-code:

```py
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import serialization
from cryptography.hazmat.primitives.asymmetric import rsa
import base64
import json

# Placeholder: Load your Tink keyset JSON, identify the key type, and decode the key material
# That is very dependent on the key type and the specifics of the Tink key format

# Assuming you have the key material as a Python bytes object for an RSA key
key_material = b'...'  # That would be the result of decoding the base64 'value' for the correct key type

# Convert the RSA key material to an RSA key object (example)
# Again, you will need to adapt that, based on actual key type and format
public_key = serialization.load_der_public_key(key_material)

# Convert to PEM format
pem = public_key.public_bytes(
    encoding=serialization.Encoding.PEM,
    format=serialization.PublicFormat.SubjectPublicKeyInfo
)

print(pem.decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: 1. Very interesting that PEM isn't a "real format". 2. "The value inside the value field is base64-encoded binary data" huh. i thought that meant itd be der. but then again. im a noob at this stuff. 3. Sounds like I'll need an additional java library to convert my tink public key `value` to send it over to my server (which is expecting a pem or der)

Comment: Let me try to get something together now and I'll ask some more detailed questions, but I'm assuming this is the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

Neither its base64-encoded. Here is a good article from Google that goes over it: https://developers.google.com/tink/wire-format

It goes over the `key's` `bites` and stuff.

Comment: thanks. the key did seem to be the fact that its a proto.